# I am getting this Error: while I am trying to install the Firmware for linux kernel Drivers

Tags: 12.04

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 213275 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to replace linux-firmware 1.79.1 (using .../linux- firmware_1.79.18_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-firmware ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb   (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu', which is also in  package bt-dw1705-firmware 0.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the `bt-dw1705-firmware` using

```
sudo apt-get purge bt-dw1705-firmware
```

and then execute

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**OR**
(*not safe*)

You can also overwrite the existing file with the new one without removing any installed package with following command

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.18_all.deb
```

and then execute

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```